# How is the bottom border color changed on a Material 3 TextField in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a parameter that can be passed to a Material 3 TextField to change the color of the bottom border?

[Compose 3 TextField Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#TextField(kotlin.String,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.input.VisualTransformation,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Int,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.material3.TextFieldColors))

I'm using androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.2

I thought I could change it in the colors parameter, but that doesn't seem to be an option that I can see.

```
colors: TextFieldColors = TextFieldDefaults.colors()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to to change indicator's color states:

```
val mutableStateOfText = remember { mutableStateOf("") }

TextField(
    placeholder = { Text("placeholder") },
    value = mutableStateOfText.value,
    onValueChange = {
        mutableStateOfText.value = it
    },
    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
    colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
        focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Red,
        unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Blue,
        disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Yellow
    )
)
```

Unfocused:
[image]

Focused:
[image]